# __builtin_popcount - is this equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, gcc

The https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html says

— Built-in Function: int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)
Returns the number of 1-bits in x.

So todo the same, I tried the following code in c#

```
        long l8 = 9;
        int iCont = Convert.ToString(l8, 2).Split('0').ToList().FindAll(x=>x=="1").Count;
```

I wanted to double check with this question in stack overflow that, if this is wrong what I did or is there any built in functions do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not.  It will fail on any number with adjacent 1s in its binary representation, because they will be together in one string after `Split('0')` and so not match `(x => x == "1")`.  Try 3, for instance.

Because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, you can use an idea similar to yours while looking at the characters directly:

`Convert.ToString(l8, 2).Count(c => c == '1')`

There are other [cleverer solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer), of course.

Comment: Thank you, I made this from that clever solutions. Completely test it though

Comment: static int __builtin_popcount(long i)
        {
             i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
             i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
             return (int)(((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;

        }